# How to save only last hour of data, with PHP

Tags: php

What is an elegant way to save only the last hour of information? In my situation, I am logging information, e.g.,:

```
Tue Nov 10 05:17:12 UTC 2015   \t   apple
Tue Nov 10 05:42:27 UTC 2015   \t   banana
Tue Nov 10 05:51:41 UTC 2015   \t   carrot
```

I only need information from the last hour. I want to save to one or more text files in a way which is simple and bulletproof. i.e., no traversing a directory to delete old files based on broad pattern matches. It's not a problem if I have 2 hours of data, but I don't want less than 1 hour.

I had an idea to alternate 2 or 3 files, sometimes logging to >1 file, and deleting one or the other specific files at certain times, but I couldn't figure out the logic.

Assume PHP. So this is on-demand from web requests, not a crontab.

Comment: configure your application to save logs on an hourly basis, this way you will have one log file per hour. Then configure `logrotate` or something similar to archive or delete logs older than x.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks I considered logrotate, and actually used it for a related purpose in the past, but it creates complexities down the road. I'd like something more standalone. My log files are actually data files which I will be using via another part of the app -- on data from the last hour only.

Comment: What do you mean by last hour? As in, if it was 4:50 you want everything written from 3:50 to 4:50 or just everything from 4:00 to 4:50 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dealt with a similar problem a while ago. My solution was use two files, saving up to the last two hours. In pseudocode:

```
 # two files
 file0 = a file
 file1 = another file

 # delete old files
 if file0 older than 2 hours, delete file0
 if file1 older than 2 hours, delete file1

 # select newest file, and delete on alternating hours
 if current hour mod 2 = 0 then
     newest file = file0; 
     delete file1;
 else
     newest file = file1;
     delete file0;

 # save data to end of file
 print data to file0; 
 print data to file1;

 # the file to use is: newest file
```

This is a little different than you want, since it's up to 2 hours, but if the main idea is that you always want the last hour, this method will work.

Here's a breakdown. F0 = file0; F1 = file1; a,b,c = data

```
 time    mod   data   clear   F0      F1      fileToUse
 23:45   1     a      F0      a       a       F1
 00:15   0     b      F1      ab      b       F0
 00:45   0     c      F1      abc     c       F0
 10:05   0     d      F0,F1   d       d       F0
 11:30   1     e      F0      e       de      F1
```

Comment: i'm not convinced, but it looks to me like that you'll end up with 0 minutes logged at the top of the hour.  consider the case that you get one php page view at 1 second before an even hour you'll use file 2 and delete file 1 then write just this one data row to file 1.  then when you get your next php page view at 1 second after the even hour, you'll use file 1 and delete file 2 then write just the one data row to file 2.  but file 1 only has the one row.

Answer (score 0):

riffing on @michaelCodes answer but uses three files.  this guarantees that there is a full hour of data in data_file.  it only logs to only two files at a time.

```
 # three files
 file0 = a file log starting at hour mod 0, deleted at hour mod 2
 file1 = a file log starting at hour mod 1, deleted at hour mod 0
 file2 = a file log starting at hour mod 2, deleted at hour mod 1

 # data_file is the last file written to (last hour + this hour)
 # current_file is just from the top of this hour (could be 1 record)

 # select newest file, and delete file from 2 hours ago
 switch (current hour mod 3)
   case 0:
     current_file = file0;
     data_file = file2;
     delete file1;
   case 1:
     current_file = file1;
     data_file = file0;
     delete file2;
   case 2:
     current_file = file2;
     data_file = file1;
     delete file0;

 # save data to all files that weren't just deleted
 print data to data_file; 
 print data to current_file;
```

Comment: It's been a while since I did this. I just swapped the mod, added a delete for old files, and made an example log. I think 3 files can work.

Answer (score 0):

in other words, any record from the log is valid only for the next 60 minutes from creation. you can use an in-memory storage system like memcached/redis. such systems have a garbage collection functionality and you can set them to do a snapshot to disk every hour or you can query for valid keys.